# Loop over items in dicts in list using Python 3 comprehensions

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Suppose I have a list with dicts, given is: each dict contains one key.

```
testlist = [{'x': 15}, {'y': 16}, {'z': 17}]

for x in testlist:
    for k, v in x.items():
        print(k,v)

# x 15
# y 16
# z 17
```

How can I use comprehensions to get the same result?
I tried this:

```
for k,v in [x.items() for x in testlist]:
    print(k,v)
```

Returns: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Comment: if you just want to print them as you done before you can do `print("\n".join([f"{k} {v}" for x in testlist for k, v in x.items()]))`

Comment: Nice exercise, but I wouldn't do it in _real_ production code: I find the first code snippet way easier to read!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make a multiloop comprehension:

```
for k,v in [pair for x in testlist for pair in x.items()]:
```

or [use `itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to do the flattening for you (somewhat more efficiently):

```
from itertools import chain

for k, v in chain.from_iterable(x.items() for x in testlist):
# Or with operator.methodcaller to move the work to the C layer:
for k, v in chain.from_iterable(map(methodcaller('items'), testlist)):
```